# Where can I apply for a third party Travel Grant?

Tags: funding, travel

I am a fresh graduate (LLB) and I was selected as an volunteer for a conference in UK (held in June 1st & 2nd). They don't provide travel or accomodation expenses.

I'm a Sri Lankan citizen who resides in Sri Lanka and this volunteering opportunity will definitely be a great experience in my life. I really can't miss this opportunity.

But as a citizen from a developing country, its really hard for me to spend on huge airfare. Is there any place/organization that I can apply for a travel grant for my volunteering? (It will be a great help if I can gain even only the airfare, then I can spend my own for accommodation)

Comment: I fail to see the reason for downvote. However, I see this question may be too broad as there may be many organizations that could help the OP's situation.

Comment: Does LLB mean "Bachelor of Laws (Latin: Legum Baccalaureus)"?

Comment: Are you presenting at the conference (paper, talk, poster, etc)?

Comment: Yes, LLB means Bachelor of Law.

I'm not presenting nor an author in the conference. I was selected as an volunteer.


I couldn't find any organisations that accept my plea yet. Please recommend me if there is any. Thanks for your responses so far.

Comment: For many travel grants, you need to present your work at a conference to be eligible. The short time line is also an issue as applications often have to be submitted months in advance (and there was only about 2 weeks between you asking this question and the start of the conference).

Answer (score 3):

1. Speak to the conference organizers, although you claim that they don't offer travel, you don't say how you know this. Have you asked them? If you approach them with a polite email expressing your intense interest and disappointment that you cannot attend, maybe some money can be found.
2. Can the conference sponsor help? Often these conferences are sponsored by a large company looking to hire fresh talent. This is a good way to get noticed, so maybe they can throw a few £100 in your direction. Make sure you talk to the right person in the company.
3. Can your (past) institution in Sri Lanka help? Don't just look at what your department offers, scour the websites for any kind of money that is available for student travel. Speak to your former advisor. Speak to the head of the department. Speak to the careers advice team.
4. Are you a member of any learned society or institute? They will often have discounted rates for students and unemployed, but offer bursaries for (recent) students attending conferences.
5. Does your government fund any programmes that might be of use?
6. Are you in a minority or in some other group that gets targeted for extra money? Don't be shy, go looking for it.

Finally, what kind of price quotes are you getting for your airfare?

Comment: +1 for "learned society" -- they're probably the best place to go for a grant that covers your specific area of interest.